# Problema en herencia usando diccionarios

Tags: python-3.x, diccionarios, herencia

Tengo el siguiente problema, una clase padre cuyo atributo es un dict, dict que heredan las clases hijas y estas deben añadir una clave:valor extra unica de su clase, pero al referenciar el dict en el constructor de la clase hija salta error diciendo que no posee ese atributo.

Clase padre

```
class Personal_Universitario():
    """Clase Personal_Universitario incluye un dict con las claves id, nombre y email """

    def __init__(self, id, nombre, email):
        self.__registro = {
            "id": id,
            "nombre": nombre,
            "email": email
        }

    @property
    def registro(self):
        return self.__registro

    @registro.setter
    def registro(self, new):
        self.__registro = new
        return self.__registro

    def __del__(self):
        return

    def __str__(self):
        return """
        > Id : {}
        > Nombre : {}
        > Email : {} """.format(self.__registro["id"], self.__registro["nombre"], self.__registro["email"])
```

Clase hija

```
class Oficina(Personal_Universitario):
    """Clase Oficina hereda datos de Personal_Universitario y añade al dict la clave Puesto """

    def __init__(self, id, nombre, email, puesto):
        super().__init__( id, nombre, email)
        self.__registro["puesto"] = puesto  #aqui es donde falla

    @property
    def registro(self):
        return self.__registro

    @registro.setter
    def registro(self, new):
        self.__registro = new
        return self.__registro

    def __del__(self):
        return

    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__() + """
        > Puesto : {}""".format(self.__registro["puesto"])
```

Creacion clase hija

```
ofi1= Oficina("AA01","Ciencias y Tecnologías", "CienciasTecnologías@universidad.com", "Profesores")
```

Error

> AttributeError: 'Oficina' object has no attribute '_Oficina__registro'

SOLUCION

Se quitan los getter y setter duplicados y se corrige el como se invoca a "registro" desde la clase hija

class Personal_Universitario():

```
"""Clase Personal_Universitario incluye un dict con las claves id, nombre y email """

def __init__(self, idpu, nombre, email):
    self.__registro = {
        "id": idpu,
        "nombre": nombre,
        "email": email
    }

@property
def registro(self):
    return self.__registro

@registro.setter
def registro(self, new):
    self.__registro = new

def __del__(self):
    return

def __str__(self):
    return """
    > Id : {}
    > Nombre : {}
    > Email : {} """.format(self.__registro["id"], self.__registro["nombre"], self.__registro["email"])
```

class Oficina(Personal_Universitario) :

```
"""Clase Oficina hereda datos de Personal_Universitario y añade al dict la clave Puesto """

def __init__(self, idpu, nombre, email, puesto):
    super().__init__(idpu, nombre, email)
    self.registro['puesto'] = puesto

def __del__(self):
    return

def __str__(self):
    return super().__str__() + """
    > Puesto : {}""".format(self.registro["puesto"])
```

Comment: El código va como texto, no como imagen, por favor [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/526029/edit) tu pregunta

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Texto en magenta sobre fondo negro no es legible.

Comment: Un diccionario es redundante y complica las cosas. En lugar de guardar en un diccionario, guarda en atributos. Será más fácil accederlos y cambiarlos.

Comment: si pero es un ejercicio de práctica y me lo piden asi

Comment: Considera cambiarte de escuela.

Comment: Hay tantos problemas con el código que sólo @abulafia tendrá la paciencia para explicarlos. Yo me doy por vencido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El diseño del código tiene muchos problemas, como menciona @CandidMoe, entre ellos los siguientes:

- Uso de atributos cuyo nombre comienza por `__` en un intento de hacer un atributo privado. Esto es una meta fútil en Python. Ningún atributo es privado, y el `__` sólo complica un poco más el acceder al mismo, pero no lo impide. En cambio es fuente de mil problemas (y precisamente lo que impide que tu código funcione).
- Uso de setters y getters (properties) que en el fondo no hacen nada (es decir, no validan los datos de ninguna forma) y son totalmente superfluos, pues para no validar nada puedes dejar perfectamente el atributo visible y que se pueda asignar desde fuera.
- Uso de un diccionario para guardar cosas que perfectamente podrían ser atributos separados del objeto, en vez de "empaquetarse juntos" en un diccionario.
- Uso del método mágico `__del__()` pero implementado vacío. ¿Esto por qué?
- Uso de un método `__str__()` que depende totalmente de que el diccionario interno `__registro` tenga las claves apropiadas, o si no romperá (pero podría no tenerlas, ya que el *setter* no valida el diccionario asignado). Esto mejor se resolvería con una `namedtuple`, si es que se insiste en tener esos atributos "empaquetados" en uno solo. Al menos con la `namedtuple` podrías chequear el tipo.

De todas formas no estoy aquí para juzgar el diseño (y más si te lo han pedido así), sino para indicarte por qué no te funciona y cómo arreglarlo.

### El problema

El problema es el atributo llamado `__registro`. Cuando un atributo comienza por doble *underscore*, Python lo trata de forma especial. Lo renombra internamente y su nuevo nombre es `_Cls__registro` (siendo `Cls` la clase del objeto en cuestión). Esto es lo que se llama *name mangling*. No obstante, desde dentro de la implementación de la clase, el propio intérprete "deshace" ese renombrado, ya que cada vez que vea que accedes a `self.__registro` lo convertirá en un acceso a `self._Cls__registro`, para que no notes nada y el acceso sea normal. Es sólo cuando intentas acceder a `objeto.__registro` desde fuera cuando no se deshace el *mangling* y así no se pueda encontrar el atributo.

Esto es un intento (bastante inocente) de impedir el acceso a ese atributo, ya que si desde fuera de la implementación de la clase tú instancias el objeto así: `objeto = Cls()` y luego intentas acceder a `objeto.__registro` te dirá que ese atributo no existe. ¡Claro, porque se ha renombrado por el intérprete! Pero basta que accedas a `objeto._Cls__registro` y ya te has saltado la ""protección"".

Así que usar nombres de atributo que comienzan por `__` en un intento de emular una propiedad privada en Python no tiene mucho sentido al final. Mejor ponerle al nombre del atributo un solo `_`. En este caso Python no hace nada especial con él. El atributo sigue siendo público, pero su nombre es una advertencia al lector de que "este atributo no está pensado para ser usado desde el exterior, mejor no lo uses". Es una petición amable, no una prohibición. Como dice Guido (el creador de Python) "*we all are consenting adults here*"

Pero es que además en este caso el *name mangling* te está causando problemas. Ya que en la clase `Personal_Universitario` asignas `self.__registro`, se estará creando (debido al *name mangling*) el atributo `self._Personal_Universitario__registro`. Y cuando luego en la clase derivada `Oficina` intentas añadir algo a `self.__registro`, lo estarás intentando añadir en cambio a `self._Oficina__registro`. Y claro, este atributo no existe.

Y es que al usar `__` delante has hecho una especie de atributo "private", pero lo que querrías sería hacer un atributo de tipo "friend" (que significa que pueda ser usado desde las clases derivadas, pero no desde fuera de ellas). Python no tiene ese concepto. En realidad tampoco tiene el de "private" pues lo del *name mangling* no es más que un *hack* que debe evitarse.

### Solución

Renombra `__registro` como `_registro` y con eso tu problema se resuelve, al desaparecer el *name mangling*.

### Nota final

Claro que entonces el atributo es "público" y para eso, como decía al principio, mejor eliminar por completo la supuesta "privacidad" de ese diccionario. Quita también el guión inicial, déjalo como `registro` y elimina el getter y setter. Así:

```
class Personal_Universitario():
    """Clase Personal_Universitario incluye un dict con las claves id, nombre y email """

    def __init__(self, id, nombre, email):
        self.registro = {
            "id": id,
            "nombre": nombre,
            "email": email
        }

    def __str__(self):
        return ("> Id : {}\n" +
                "> Nombre : {}\n" +
                "> Email : {}".format(
                    self.registro["id"], 
                    self.registro["nombre"], 
                    self.registro["email"])
        )

class Oficina(Personal_Universitario):
    """Clase Oficina hereda datos de Personal_Universitario y añade al dict la clave Puesto """

    def __init__(self, id, nombre, email, puesto):
        super().__init__( id, nombre, email)
        self.registro["puesto"] = puesto  #aqui es donde falla

    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__() + "\n> Puesto : {}".format(self.registro["puesto"])


ofi1= Oficina("AA01","Ciencias y Tecnologías", "CienciasTecnologias@universidad.com", "Profesores")
print(ofi1)
```

Y obtienes:

```
> Id : AA01
> Nombre : Ciencias y Tecnologías
> Email : CienciasTecnologias@universidad.com
> Puesto : Profesores
```

Y aún puedes seguir haciendo si quieres `print(ofi1.registro)` o cambiarlo con `of1.registro = otro_diccionario`

Comment: Lo primero muchas gracias, llevo apenas un mes aprendiendo a programar y se agradece todo la ayuda.

Ya corregí el problema, duplique los setter y los getters dentro de la clase hija sin necesidad e invocaba al dict de forma erronea como comentas desde el constructor  de la clase hija.

En cuanto a lo de hacer los atributos "privados" y los setters, nos dijeron que era recomendable ponerlos en privado con __ y luego crear unos getter y setter para poder interactuar con las variables atributos pero sin hacerlo de forma directo

Comment: En cuanto a lo del los getter y setter entiendo por lo que dices que se les añade algun tipo de filtro mediante condicionales etc  para aceptar o rechazar el tipo de dato que le llega ¿correcto?.

El metodo _ _ del _ _ lo incluyo para poder eliminar un objeto, ¿no es necesario? ¿se emplea con otro fin ?

Comment: Sí, las razones para usar un getter suelen ser para hacer que ciertos valores que en realidad tienen que ser computados por una función aparezcan ante el usuario de ese objeto como si fueran atributos pre-almacenados. Por ejemplo, puedes tener una propiedad llamada `.is_valid` que sea `True` o `False`, y que puedas consultar mediante `objeto.is_valid`, que tiene pinta de ser un atributo, pero podría estar implementado como una propiedad que llame al correspondiente _getter_, por lo que el valor puede ser computado en vez de almacenado

Comment: Los _setter_ a su vez se usan para controlar qué se mete en una propiedad. Puedes verificar por ejemplo que el diccionario que llega tenga las claves que tiene que tener, y lo rechace (eleve una excepción) si no es así. De ese modo el usuario intentaría `objeto.record = {"cosa": "mal"}` y eso causará la ejecución del setter, que podría generar una excepción en vez de almacenar el dato.

Comment: Pero ambas cosas no son más que azúcar sintáctico opcional, ya que perfectamente para el primer caso podrías tener una función (método) en vez de una property, y llamarla así: `objeto.is_valid()`, y para el segundo análogamente `objeto.store_record(datos)`

Comment: El patrón que estabas usando tú parece hecho por alguien que viene de programar en Java o C++, lenguajes en los que hay una cierta obsesión por ocultar datos en las clases, marcándolos como  "private", para que no se pueda acceder a ellos desde fuera de la clase. En estos lenguajes para dar acceso (controlado) a esos atributos no queda otra que implementar getters y setters. Pero en python la filosofía es más bien dejarlo todo público haciendo innecesarios los getters y setters . Lo más paraecido a un atributo privado es el que empieza por `__` aunque ya has visto que plantean problemas.

Comment: ok osea entiendo que usando el _ _ y luego hacer uso de getters y setters realmente no estoy segurizando nada o se hace de forma muy leve

Comment: Asi es. Python no es Java. Tratar de implementar en python los patrones típicos de Java solo lleva a código más farragoso. En la mayoría de los casos la versión más "pythónica" es mucho más simple.

Comment: entiendo que la seguridad se implementa mas adelante con otras herramientas

Comment: No. En realidad la ocultación de atributos no tiene nada qué ver con la seguridad. Si tu API está bien diseñada y documentada, quienes usen tus clases deberían hacer uso de la documentación y usar la clase en la forma en que en ella se explique. Si tienes atributos que marcas como "internos" y "no usar", pues no deberían usarlos. El lenguaje no va a poner trabas sin embargo si alguien los usa directamente. Pero será bajo su cuenta y riesgo, puesto que tú puedes más adelante cambiar la implementación (por ejemplo renombrar un atributo interno) y quien lo usara dejará de funcionar bien.

Comment: No es seguridad "real", solo son salvaguardas para evitar errores. Pero ese tipo de errores se evitan también con una buena documentación, la declaración opcional de tipos y un chequeador estático de código, y una buena batería de tests

Comment: Por cierto, debemos evitar debates extensos en comentarios. Si te apetece pásate por el chat y lo hablamos alli, pero no ahora que me tengo que ir. Ah, y si la respuesta resolvió tu problema no olvides marcarla como aceptada

Comment: Ah vale de acuerdo muchas gracias buenas noches